# Change linear plot to 100% plot in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

Recently I have used this input for WolframAlpha:

`Plot (forumla1), (formula2), (formula3), {a, 0, 50}`

It's generating "Linear Plot" like on picture on left. Is there way to make it generate "100%" plot like on picture on right? So that it will sum up, look of how big percentage formula generates and match it?
[image: Generated using Microsoft Word 2013]

This isn't WolframAlpha, I used another software for generation.

I tried `region`  function, but it doesn't work with 3 formula's apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a bit. It looks there is possibility but it only supports 2 regions and it doesn't really make it 100%, but it makes visible the "territory" between variables. =

`region (formula1) < (formula2)`